# Invalid Column name when using INNER JOIN to get values from two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables:

tbl_profiles_and_users:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[profile_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[user_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

tbl_profiles_and_activities:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[profile_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[user_id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[activity_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[check] [int] NULL,
[preferred] [int] NULL
```

both tables have entries in them, and I am trying to select the user, and activities, only from within a specified profile.

I am trying to do this with the following join:

```
use [dbName]

SELECT p1.user_id AS User_ID, [p2.activity_name] as [Activity_Name]
FROM tbl_profiles_and_users AS p1 
INNER JOIN tbl_profiles_and_activities AS p2 
ON p1.user_id = p2.user_id AND p1.profile_id = p2.profile_id
```

but I receive the message 
Invalid column name 'p2.activity_name'
What am I doing wrong? Can I achieve the desired results with a Join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because you are escaping the whole column, thus, the server reads it as `[p2.activity_name]` as *whole* column name which is very different from `[p2].[activity_name]`

```
SELECT p1.user_id AS User_ID, [p2].[activity_name] as [Activity_Name]
FROM ....
```

Comment: (Actually a [`delimited identifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033(v=sql.80).aspx), not escaped.)

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution. I will accept your answer when the timer allows it.

Comment: @RedFilter yeah you're right.  was trying to figure out what the correct term. Thanks!